# wkhtmltopdf, encoding cyrillic from perl pipe

Tags: perl, encoding, wkhtmltopdf

So, i'm running wkhtmltopdf command script from perl's `system` method. I need it to pass a custom value (span class) to pdf via command line:

my $time = "Время";
my $command = "./wkhtmltopdf ...blablabla... gen_date \"$time\" ...blablabla...";

but when i run this - i have encoding garbage in output .pdf like that: - Ð​ÑÐμÐ¼Ñ.
Tried almost everything i know to encode/decode the `$time` string, but nothing.

my javascript snippet is common for wkhtmltopdf, so....

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<head>
  <script>
    function subst() {
      var vars = {};
      var query_strings_from_url = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
      for (var query_string in query_strings_from_url) {
        if (query_strings_from_url.hasOwnProperty(query_string)) {
          var temp_var = query_strings_from_url[query_string].split('=', 2);
          vars[temp_var[0]] = decodeURI(temp_var[1]);
        }
      }
      var css_selector_classes = ['gen_date', 'page'];
      for (var css_class in css_selector_classes) {
        if (css_selector_classes.hasOwnProperty(css_class)) {
          var element = document.getElementsByClassName(css_selector_classes[css_class]);
          for (var j = 0; j < element.length; ++j) {
            element[j].textContent = vars[css_selector_classes[css_class]];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
```

Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://ahinea.com/en/tech/perl-unicode-struggle.html)

Comment: Can you please provide the exact steps to reproduce your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#Help_others_reproduce_the_problem

Comment: @daxim already solved.

Answer (score 0):

After finding a rason why does it happen, i realiased that JS is more likely to operate with its format of byte-array. Now, cyrillic string is encoded to be look like `%u0000%u0000...` and then in javascript, this string goes through built-in `unescape` function, and now i have normal cyrillic string in pdf.

Oh, my...